# How can I get the post ID from a WP_Query loop?

Tags: post-meta

I have a WP_Query loop that gets posts of a certain type.  These posts have custom post meta so I need to be able to get the ID of the post without echoing it so I can display that post's meta.  How can I get the ID of the post without echoing it?  This is my code:

```
$menu_id = get_the_id();
        $category_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'category',
            'post_parent' => $menu_id
        );

        $menu_categories = new WP_Query($category_args);
        while($menu_categories->have_posts()) : $menu_categories->the_post(); 
            $category_id = ??????; ?>
        <h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4><?php 

            $dish_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'dish',
                'post_parent' => $category_id
            );
            $category_dishes = new WP_Query($dish_args);
            while($category_dishes->have_posts()) : $category_dishes->the_post(); 
                $dish_meta = get_post_meta(???????);?>
            <h6><?php echo the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $dish_meta[0]['price']; ?></h6>
            <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p><?php
            endwhile;
        endwhile;
```

Comment: `$post_id = get_the_ID();` can be used within the loop. This retrieves the ID of current post handled by the loop.

Comment: @N00b you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to get categories, or have you a custom post type called "category"? If the former then you should be using [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) if the latter then you should read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

Answer (score 30):

`get_the_ID()` can *(only)* be used within the loop.

This retrieves the `ID` of the current post handled by the loop.

---

You can use it on it's own if you need it only once:

```
$dish_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dish_meta', true );
```

You can also store it as a variable if you need it more than once:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$dish_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'dish_meta', true );

$drink_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'drink_meta', true );

print_r( $post_id );

//etc
```

---

Reference: [get_the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Answer (score 6):

get_the_ID() function will give you post ID..,

```
            $args = array(

                          's' => $_POST['search_text'],
                          'posts_per_page' => -1,
                          'post_type' => 'address'

                     );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

               while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

                    $query->the_post();

                    $address_post_id = get_the_ID() ;
               }
            }
```